# How can I get a listing of all users and their AD exchange settings?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, scripting, reporting

I'm open to different methods, from scripting to open source software, but I need a list of all active directory users, and some settings about them, specifically, the Exchange Advanced tab's settings.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Quest AD PowerShell addins.  They are free and should be able to pull all that info.

Comment: I can't download anything from this site.

Comment: Strange, it appears to be working for me today. I downloaded from http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and used ADManager Plus to get the desired information.  It had a report already made to find hidden mailboxes in exchange.  The demo period is 30 days and then the product goes into limited mode, but worked like a charm today.